# Why is there some error with my XML in my android application

Tags: java, android, xml

on my MainActivity it is not reading my r properly which means an XML error AFAIK. I can't find the issue though.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" //error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
    </ListView>
 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.viewsqltest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private String jsonResult;
 private String url = "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";
 private ListView listView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  accessWebService();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
    String outPut = name + "-" + number;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
  return employeeNameNo;
 }
}
```

Errors:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /viewsqltest/src/com/example/viewsqltest    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /viewsqltest/src/com/example/viewsqltest    line 37 Java Problem
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)   activity_main.xml
/viewsqltest/res/layout line 3  Android AAPT Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /viewsqltest/src/com/example/viewsqltest    line 45 Java Problem

Finally, if you want the manifest it's here:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.viewsqltest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.viewsqltest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks, need anything else let me know
  edit: commented an error where it came up

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: Hey, the R file is not generating due to some error so I can't

Comment: did you tried to remove the line and build again? the line ist not important in this case, so you can remove it

Comment: also remove `tools:context=".MainActivity"`with that line

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. Yeah I removed the two lines about tools:context but I'm still getting an error in the XML somewhere, this time it's just on "error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)" on a different line. I'm gonna edit the answer to include ErrorLog too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my error, the problem was that I was copy pasting code from a tutorial and during the copy & paste there was some characters left in the white space that I couldn't see. I fixed the problem by deleting all the spaces and putting them back in. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

At the top of the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would do is check the error Log, in eclipse go to window>show view> error log

If you added any resources lately make sure the resources all match proper naming standards,  they can't start with a capital letter or have special characters.  if they all seem ok, i would delete the R.java file from your gen folder and do a clean and build

also you don't seem to be using the xmls:tools  take it out.

Comment: Check my answer if you like, I fixed it. I just had white space that copy and pasted weirdly. Thanks for your help though!